# What is the best practice to manage records in has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: User, Group and GroupUser

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, through: :group_users

class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user`
```

and I create a form for given group with checkboxes for all users, so I can see whether or not each user is in the group, and I can check any user to add to group or uncheck if user belongs to group. Then after submitting the form I get an array of id's of users to be in the group.

**My question is:** what is the best way to code such after submit operation (multiple add/deletion records) into controller or somewhere else.

For this purpose I created two additional actions in GroupsController: `def select_users` for opening checkbox form and `def add_users` for additions and deletions.

```
  def select_users
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  end

  def add_users
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  # Add new users
    new_users = params[:group][:user_ids]
    old_users = @group.users.map {|x| x.id.to_s } + [""]
    add_users = new_users.reject { |item| old_users.include?(item) }

    add_users.each do |id|
      @group.users << User.find(id)
    end

# Delete unwanted users
    delete_users = old_users.reject { |item| new_users.include?(item) }
    @group.group_users.where(user_id: delete_users).destroy_all

    redirect_to groups_path, notice: 'Users were added.'

  end`
```

I could have created controller GroupUser for join table and put that actions where as RESTful 'new' and 'create', but I am not sure it's best way to do.

Comment: Also `def select_users` is pretty confusing.  If you were going to name that I would call it find_group.  That said it makes no sense to define it then not use it in add_users.  If you want to define something like that and use it in a before action in your controller that would be ok but as it is I don't think it is really helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to have a skinny controller and a fat model.  So I would not put those two methods on your controller.  The controller should call a single model method ideally.  So I would change this:

```
def add_users


@group = Group.find(params[:id])
  # Add new users
  new_users = params[:group][:user_ids]
  old_users = @group.users.map {|x| x.id.to_s } + [""]
  add_users = new_users.reject { |item| old_users.include?(item) }

  add_users.each do |id|
    @group.users << User.find(id)
  end
end
```

to something on the Group model

```
def update_users(user_ids)
  new_users = User.where(id: user_ids)
  final_users = new_users + self.users
  self.users = final_users.uniq
  self.save
end
```

As far as restful convention I would put this on the update action for groups controller and use the accepts_nested_attributes_for option.

```
def update
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  if @group.update_users(params[:group][:user_ids])
    #handle success
  else
   #handle error
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't do all this stuff in the GroupsController--it's cluttering it up. Create a new plain ruby class to handle it.

2) Not sure but I bet you can assign users to a collection and it will write over the association. As such:

```
@group.users = User.where(id: [1,2,4]) # you can just give it your params[:group][:user_ids] here as the array
@group.save! # also not sure if this is necessary
```

Comment: This is another valid option.  Personally for the behavior in it's current form I wouldn't use a form backing object.  That said if groups got any more complicated I would use a PORO(plain old ruby object) as a form backing object.  For more on that see this article: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit  I would say given the perceived skill level of OP form backing objects may be a bit advanced but not a bad way to solve this.